# Accept binary file in body of request on a node.js server

Tags: node.js, file-upload, busboy

I want to upload a binary file in the body of a `POST`.

I do NOT want to use a `multipart/form-data`.

(As far as I know `multipart/form-data` is an easy to use technology for web apps, but not easy for mobile apps. I don't have a web app, I'm just building mobile apps.)

I've tried using busboy, but haven't been able to find anything on non `multipart/form-data` uploads. `express-fileupload` also uses the same thing AFAIK.

Answer (score 5):

So if I understand correctly, you want to create a route that will be used to upload files to the server. One way to do this is by using the body-parser express middleware combined with a write stream:

```
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

app.post('/upload/:image', bodyparser.raw({
    limit: '10mb', 
    type: 'image/*'
}), (req, res) => {
    const image = req.params.image;
    const fd = fs.createWriteStream(`[SERVER_UPLOAD_PATH]/${image}`, {
        flags: "w+",
        encoding: "binary"
    });
    fd.end(req.body);
    fd.on('close', () => res.send({status: 'OK'});
});
```

Sending the following request will upload the file to the [SERVER_UPLOAD_PATH]:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: image/png' --data-binary @[image-path]/image.png http://[server-url]/upload/image.png
```

The above example is used to upload images to the server but you can modify it accordingly. Note that you will need to check for the file type to make sure that the users are uploading only the file types that they are supposed to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm having troubles getting the image from req.params.image. It's `undefined`. I am using PostMan to send the POST. Would you be able to show how you'd upload using PostMan? I'm setting the header `Content-Type` to `image/png` and setting `body` to `binary` and uploading my own image, `image.png`.

Comment: there was a typo in my code:) In the route name I used '.../:file' but then I wrote req.params.image instead of req.params.file - I have edited the answer and it should now work.

Comment: Nice, I think this will work. I'm having problems getting the right path to write to. Could you give an example of what it could be just to get it to work?

Comment: I don't know node well. I'm guessing I can get the image data from req.body after the write stream is closed? where `res.send({status: 'OK'}` is currently?

Comment: As long as you don't use `return`  with `fd.on('close', () => ...)` you can keep using the image data from req.body. For example this would print the image's Buffer:

`fd.on('close', () => res.send({status: 'OK'});`
`console.log(req.body);`