# Accept binary file in body of request on a Nest.js server

Tags: node.js, angular, express, binaryfiles

I want to access the binary file uploaded data from the browser.

Nest.js server application works fine from postman but application throws a 400 error when the request is made from the Google Chrome/Angular application.

Thoughts on how to make the Nest.js application accept binary file data? Please let me know.

Attachments for reference:

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtjXH.png)

[Google Chrome Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYAfS.png)

Comment: Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034468/accept-binary-file-in-body-of-request-on-a-node-js-server

Comment: Typically this is due to the request bodies being different. It would be useful if you could show us the request body from the network tab of Chrome, and the request from Postman, and highlight the differences.

Comment: @AdamExchange - Please see the attachments for reference, thanks.

Comment: Response received from Nest.js server on the browser:  {"statusCode":400,"message":"Unexpected field","error":"Bad Request"}

Comment: The difference is that Google Chrome is sending binary data and postman is sending form data. Also, the server accepts the request from postman, but the request is not even accepted by the server when made from browser.

Comment: Are you trying to make Nest support binary data, or have Chrome send Form Data. (The second is pretty easy to do in Angular, making the Angular request closer to the Postman request so it works).

Answer (score 0):

When I needed receive binary data I used library [raw-body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-body)

And add middleware

```
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '100mb' }));
```

then create decorator

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import getRawBody from 'raw-body';

export const RawBody = createParamDecorator(async (_, context: ExecutionContext) => {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest<import('express').Request>();
    if (req.readable) { 
        const reqBody = (await getRawBody(req)).toString('utf8').trim();
        try {
            const body = JSON.parse(reqBody);
            if(body) {
                return body;
            }
        } catch {}
    }   
    throw new BadRequestException('Invalid body');
})
```

And example of usage:

```
@Controller('upload')
export class UploadController {
    constructor(
        private _uploadService: UploadService
    ) {}
    
    @Post()
    upload(@RawBody() body) {
        return this._uploadService.uploadImage(body);
    }
}
```